# Append or prepend selected text to a file in Vim

Tags: vim, save, backup, selection

In Vim, is there a way to move the selected text into `<current_file>.bak`, appending or prepending?
If possible, the backup file should not be displayed.

I envision the workflow to be:

1. Select some text
2. Type `:sbak`
3. The selection is saved into `<current_file>.bak`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do it in three steps:

- type <kbd>Shift-v</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>...<kbd>j</kbd> to select some lines
- type **`:'<,'>w! >>file.bak`** to save selected lines to `file.bak`(append)
- type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to delete original lines

You can write a user-defined command **`Sbak`** if you like:

```
com! -nargs=1 -range Sbak call MoveSelectedLinesToFile(<f-args>)
fun! MoveSelectedLinesToFile(filename)
    exec "'<,'>w! >>" . a:filename
    norm gvd
endfunc
```

Comment: good, now further steps:

1. to auto use <current_file>.bak as the bak filename
2. prepend not append.

thx.

Comment: use `expand('%:t')` to get current file name

Comment: As usual, you forgot to `fnameescape()` `a:filename`.

Comment: Omitting the file name after `>>` will append to the current file. Use `e:` afterwards to refresh the buffer and view the appended lines.

Answer (score 13):

What about

1. <kbd>v</kbd>
2. some movement command/even search to select the text
3. `:'<,'> w! >> /YOUR/SELECTIONFILE`
4. `:'<,'>d`

Is that what you want? If so set up a `map` for it, like

```
map <F2> :'<,'> w! >> /YOUR/SELECTIONFILE<cr>:'<,'>d<cr>
```

*Note* this appends to `SELECTIONFILE`, **and** not only the selection, but the whole lines. Also, read `:h :w` and `:h ++opt` (in which you can learn about the possible options for writing files (e.g.) you can append to a file with different encoding, which really messes things, so don't do that ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**You can write text selected by vim [marks](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_marks) into a file using the below commands.**

*For example you go to line `:20` and then mark it `ma` and then go to line 30 `:30` and mark it `mb` and then copy lines 20 to 30 to file filename.dat `:'a,'b w filename.dat`.*

`:'a,'b w filename.dat` to write lines from mark **a** to mark **b** into file filename.dat

`:'a,'b w! filename.dat` to replace the existing file filename.dat with lines from mark **a** to mark **b**

`:'a,'b w >> filename.dat` to append lines from mark **a** to mark **b** into file filename.dat

Comment: looks promising but does not work when filepath has spaces and/or special chars on it and the file resides in a different dir. Likewise when you try the same but with fnameescape(filename.dat)